# Rails - How to avoid multiple querys on this

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this set of tables (I'm using postgresql)

```
User (with id, first_name, ....)
Assignment (with id, name, start_date, finish_date,....)
AssignmentUser(with assignment_id, user_id, flag_status)
```

The flag_status is a boolean that says if a user is still or not in an assignment.

Let's say user1 applies for assignment1, assignment2, assignment3 as follows:

```
                        start_date     finish_date   flag_status
user1  assignment1      11-11-11       11-12-11      false
user1  assignment2      01-10-11       01-02-12      true
user1  assignment3      01-01-12       01-03-12      true
```

Let's say I want to search TODAY the closest start_date of an user's assignment.

I've done this in my User model:

```
  def last_date
    self.assignments.where("date < ?", Date.today).max.try(:date)
  end
```

and this

```
def last_status
  AssignmentUser.find_by_assignment_id_and_user_id(Assignment.find_by_date(self.last_date), self.id).flag_status if self.last_date.present?
end
```

And in my view for each user:

```
User.all.each do |u|
  <td>   u.first_name   </td>
  <td>   u.last_date   </td>
  <td>   u.last_status  </td>
end
```

It works well but, in my log I see 3 queries for each user (as expected).
So my question is: how can I avoid these multiple queries? (I guess it's more like a SQL question than a Rails one)

Answer (score 1):

```
@au = AssignmentUsers.find_by_sql(
  "SELECT assignment_users.user_id, MAX(assignment_users.date) as last_date,
   assignment_id, 
   assignments.flag_status,
   users.first_name
  FROM assignment_users
  LEFT JOIN assignments
   ON assignments.id = assignment_id
  LEFT JOIN users
   ON users.id = user_id
  WHERE date < CURDATE()
  GROUP BY user_id;"
 )
```

Then in your view:

```
@au.each do |u|
 <tr>
   <td>   u.first_name   </td>
   <td>   u.last_date    </td>
   <td>   u.last_status  </td>
 </tr>
end
```

PLEASE NOTE: this is iterating over AssignmentUsers, so if there are any users who are without an assignment they will be missed. IF that isn't good enough (i.e. you don't want to pull back a 2nd list - easily done by User.all(:conditions => "id NOT IN (#{@au.collect(&:user_id}) - then this solution isn't suitable and if that's the case, then i think you're already probably doing it the best way, although i would have changed your methods to scopes - if you want me to show you how that would look let me know.

Comment: it's a mistake it should be <td>u.last_date</td> :)

Comment: I tried and I got an error  PGError: ERROR:  sintax error near «LEFT»
LINE 6:              LEFT JOIN users.id = assignment_users.user_id A...
                     ^
: SELECT users.*,
             assignment_users.user_id,
             assignment_users.assignment_id,
             (SELECT id as last_assignment_id, date as last_date FROM assigntments WHERE date < CURDATE()), 
             assignment.flag_status as flag_status
             LEFT JOIN users.id = assignment_users.user_id AND last_assignment_id = assignment_users.assignment_id
             FROM users

Comment: above answer changed due to feedback

Comment: Actually the date column is on assignments table, how can I modify it?

Comment: line 2: `MAX(assignment_users.date)` => `MAX(assignments.date)`

Comment: I made that change, I read it wrong. The problem is (and maybe you have seen it before) PostgreSQL may be a little more specific than MySQL. I'm now getting an error of adding assignment_users.assignment_id in the GROUP BY but it shouldn't be there

Comment: Hum. So it's coming back with multi assignments per user then?

Comment: actually I had to add this data after the group by assignment_users.assignment_id, assignment_users.flag_status, users.first_name, then it show multiple data